# An oriented Grassmannian is a product of two spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to prove that the Grassmannian of oriented subspaces $\mathrm{Gr}_+(2,4,\mathbb R)$ is homeomorphic to $S^2\times S^2$? I know that $\mathrm{Gr}_+(2,4,\mathbb R)\cong\mathrm{SO}(4)/(\mathrm{SO}(2)\times\mathrm{SO}(2))$, but don't know whether this can help.

Comment: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~klin/Gr24.pdf

Comment: It is also in Besse's book "manifolds all of whose geodesics are closed."